# Path parameters separated by @ in swagger spec

Tags: python, json, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I have a swagger spec(JSON) in which I have a path which has two path parameters separated by @. When I validate the spec with OpenAPI generator I get this following error.

OpenAPI generator assuming middlename}@{lastname as one path parameter. How to solve this issue?

Error:

```
-attribute paths.'/human/{firstname}/me/{middlename}@{lastname}'. Declared path parameter middlename}@{lastname needs to be defined as a path parameter in path or operation level
```

This is my swagger spec file. I using OpenAPI version 6.0.1

```
"/human/{firstname}/me/{middlename}@{lastname}": {
    "get": {
      "operationId": "someid",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "middlename",
          "in": "path",
          "required": true,
          "schema": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "lastname",
          "in": "path",
          "required": true,
          "schema": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "height",
          "in": "query",
          "schema": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "firstname",
          "in": "path",
          "required": true,
          "schema": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      ],
      "responses": {
        "default": {
          "description": "default response",
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

I am expecting to identify middlename and lastname as two different path parameters without changing the path/endpoint.

Comment: " have a path which has two path parameters separated by @"
Such API design doesn't follow HTTP semantics, so probably you won't find any tooling supporting it. I suggest handling it as one parameter in the web layer, and splitting by @ in a more inner layer.

Comment: "I using OpenAPI version 6.0.1" is it about OpenAPI Generator or the OpenAPI specification?

Comment: @szogoon, it is OpenAPI generator version

Comment: Open an issue with the OpenAPI Generator https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues As far as I know, OpenAPI Specification doesn't have any restrictions on the number of path parameters within a single path segment, so your definition is valid. But some tools only support a single parameter per path segment.

Comment: @Helen, Issue is not with the number of path parameters. The issue is OpenAPI generator assuming 'middlename}@{lastname' as a path parameter.

Comment: Have you tried with the newest version? If it still fails - I would create an issue, like @Helen mentioned.

Comment: based on your url.. what is the purpose of this api?  what are you expecting to return for this resource?    /human/sam/me/six@seven seems like a strange way to query for a person's name.  are you expecting to have a lot of humans named sam and then further filter them by middle and last name?   you might consider using query parameters to filter on the top level collection of humans...  something like.   /humans?firstName=Sam&middleName=Six&lastName=Seven